# ¿Por qué no puedo acceder a estos datos?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy aprendiendo Vue Js y quiero desarrollar una pequeña aplicación con la que traigo distintos datos de acuerdo a lo que ingrese en un .

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="noticia in totalNoticias" :key="noticia.id">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      noticias: [],
    };
  },
 methods: {
   try {
  const parametro = this.$route.params.id;
  return (await this.axios
  .get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/noticiasPorSeccion/" + id)).data;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
} 
 },
};
</script>
```

Aquí una muestra de lo que obtengo en consola al correr esta aplicación, como se podrá apreciar cada vez que selecciono alguna sección del rombo me trae las noiticias correspondientes, pero en forma de promesas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes no es propiamente de vue.js sino más bien de promesas.

La función `traerNoticias` es una función asíncrona, tú la defines de este modo cuando escribes async antes del nombre de tu función.

Si esperas que una función asíncrona te regrese algún valor necesitas retornar algo y tu función no está retornando nada. y cómo no estás retornando nada, entonces tu función no resuelve nunca la promesa, por eso al momento de leerla está pendiente.

La forma correcta para ese modo de trabajo sería:

```
  async traerNoticias() {
    try {
      const parametro = this.$route.params.id;
      return (await this.axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/noticiasPorSeccion/" + id)).data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
  },
```

Otro error que veo ahí es que en el `string` que le estás pasando a el método `get`, incluye un `id` el cual por lo que veo está indefinido, lo correcto creo que sería agregar ahí la constante `parametro` de la siguiente forma:

```
  async traerNoticias() {
    try {
      const parametro = this.$route.params.id;
      return (await this.axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/noticiasPorSeccion/" + id)).data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } 
  },
```

Pero de cualquier modo las propiedades computadas no están diseñadas para hacer peticiones dentro de ellas, en todo caso deberías utilizar un `watcher`

Antes de continuar con la respuesta te recomiendo dos cosas:

- estudiar promesas y async await
- estudiar sobre `watchers` en vue.js

Te recomiendo hacer lo anterior antes de continuar con tu proyecto.

Continuando con mi repuesta:

Los `watchers` también observan cambios en tu código, pueden observar el cambio del id y ejecutar código ahí.

Me parece que el ejemplo completo sería:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      noticias: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async traerNoticias() {
      try {
        this.noticias = (
          await this.axios.get(
            "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/noticiasPorSeccion/" + this.parametro
          )
        ).data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    parametro() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    parametro() {
      this.traerNoticias();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Salvo a que lo pruebes pues no tengo acceso a tu api esto resolvería tu problema